# Java/Selenium automation click on xpath

Tags: java, xpath, selenium, automation, click

Can not click on link ENG

inspect element:

```
<a class="inactive" href="up/../orders;jsessionid=plhvSY2PZQpwKCLqKn7y3GBnb8nZDVn5dfXWwjPHpRX4m1skcLcg!742200689?request_locale=en">
Text - ENG
```

Java code:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'ENG')]")).click();
```

Maybe I should try href?

Comment: Inspect Element: <a class="inactive" href="up/../orders;jsessionid=plhvSY2PZQpwKCLqKn7y3GBnb8nZDVn5dfXWwjPHpRX4m1skcLcg!742200689?request_locale=en">   and Text - ENG

Comment: is the element visible and enabled? selenium can only click elements that a user also could click

Comment: yes this link to change language to ENG.In browser I see ENG and when do inspect element result is above.

Comment: what error does selenium produce? you could also check with isDisplayed() on the element you found if selenium also thinks that it should be clickable

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with xpath == //*[text()='ENG'] (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 360 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html

Comment: I was even trying find element by href looking for text inside this href "locale=en"

Comment: check if the element is inside an iframe or frame - if yes, then you have to switch to this iframe/frame first in selenium (see javadocs and tutorials for selenium)

Comment: this element is in Header of page. I was thinking that by default it is focused in something therefore I run  - public static void unFocus() {
        getDriver().switchTo().defaultContent();
    } - first then try to find element. Still can not find.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this,

```
new WebDriverWait(driver,60).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.linkText("ENG"))).click();
```

Comment: Thanks every one, problem was with frame. I add /index?frameContainer=true/ to my web page link and all variations above start working. I was looking for i frame, didn't find therefore skip this variant at first.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of locating by xpath you could try using the PartialLinkText locator.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("ENG")).click();
```